# What will happen when we cannot find minimum through gradient descent?

Tags: gradient-descent

Suppose that we have cost function with degree of 3. Based on gradient descent, we may have a derivative of zero in one or two points,but none of them specify the minimum of the cost function in those points. What will happen when we come across this?

Comment: What do you mean by "degree" of cost function?

Comment: I mean x^3. Suppose our cost fn is like it

Comment: With $x^3$, ordinary gradient descent would diverge to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

If the function is cubic, it has either no, one or two stationary points (SPs), i.e. places where the gradient is zero.

[image]

1. If there are no stationary points, the gradient descent will converge to $-\infty$ (that is the function value converges to $-\infty$).
2. If there is exactly one stationary point, gradient descent would almost surely converge to $-\infty$. However, if the algorithm is initialized in exactly the stationary point, it would remain there.
   You could also be extremely "lucky$"^i$, that after running a few steps, you end up exactly in the stationary point, and converge. However, most likely, you would take a gradient step that brings you just past the stationary point, in which case you converge to $-\infty$.
3. If there are two stationary points $x_1, x_2$ and assume WLOG that $x_1 < x_2$ and $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$. If your initialization is $x$, you converge to $f(x_1)$ if $x < x_2$ and otherwise to $-\infty$.

$^i$ In practice you would have to reverse engineer your initialization for this. If you randomly draw the initialization and use a fixed step size, this happens wit probability $0$.

Comment: Thanks, that is true. Why I asked this question was that, mostly we do not care about this. We just add some layers or neurons and then just trial and error to train the model. Almost nobody care about, in that model there is at all any minimum or that will be -inf?

Comment: @MahdiAmrollahi loss in machine learning is non-negative, so the minimum is zero, that is a perfect fit, it cannot go lower.

Comment: Yes, true. Just suppose we have a lost function from degree=3. It is possible, when we do modify layers or neurons. So, how do we find the minimum by gradient descend?

Answer (score 2):

In general gradient descent (GD) will find the local minimum of a function. But with a poorly set learning rate (LR), you may not be able to find even the local minimum. This happens when the LR is too high or too low; here is an example of a function with degree 2

[image]

The **left image** shows a GD with a learning rate **too high**, so the function bounce from the left side to the right one without properly finding the local minimum.

The **right image** shows a GD with a learning rate **too low**, so the function makes very small steps and will (or not) find the local minimum in a long time.

I hope this has clarified your doubts